# jQuery - removing a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a project, where I got stuck with some user interfacing tweaks, where I need to remove some HTML div elements.

Please check this code http://jsfiddle.net/YVZH5/ If you click the text you will see the blue tag. I need to remove that tag when the user clicks the X. But it is not working.

And It is working here http://jsfiddle.net/Jst4v/ So, where is the problem occurs?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if someday jsfiddle website goes down or permanently closes? This question will be worthless to everybody. Please put the relevant and optimal code that describes your problem here to make this question single and whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to chage

```
$("#service-sets").click(function(){
    $("#facebook-tag").remove();
});
```

to

```
$("#service-sets").on('click', '#facebook-del', function(){
    $("#facebook-tag").remove();
});
```

Because, `#facebook-del` (cross icon) will remove the tags and they come to DOM after DOM ready, so they need delegate i.e live events.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/w3hXe/2/)**

Comment: Thanks It is working, but could you be more descriptive for the last two lines. I couldn't get it? **they come to DOM dynamically** what does it mean? Thank!

Comment: That means when the HTML page is generated the first time, there is no element with 'id = facebook-del'. The element is created dynamically and hence there is no event ('click') that is attached to it. This is as per my understanding. Please correct if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works in your first fiddle and not in your second is because the element you're trying to attach a click function to (facebook-del) does not exist in the DOM at the time of assignment.

In the second example, the element exists on page load and thus gets assigned the click function.

Try looking at .on() as a way to assign your click events to dynamically added elements like this.